# Клиент для SOAP веб-сервиса

Tags: java, soap

Есть веб-сервис soap, который позволяет получить данные о пациенте. Есть ссылка wsdl: http://81.24.84.134:500/Insurance_Request.asmx?wsdl. Как написать клиента для этого веб-сервиса? С чего начать вообще?

Comment: Если вам надо просто сделать несколько вызовов, а не писать своего клиента, то используйте SoapUI. Если же вам надо делать вызовы из своего приложения, то скачиваете wsdl по ссылк (возможно также xsd) и генерируете классы с помощью wsimport (в Oracle JDK) или Apache CXF, также существуют плагины для мавена. Подробнее ищите в гугле "java generate stub from wsdl". Далее уже гуглите как сделать вызов с помощью сгенерированных классов. Например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15940234/how-to-do-a-soap-web-service-call-from-java-class

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать.